# C# Stringbuilder replace with a null value

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, character-replacement

Im trying to use Stringbuilder to build me a csv file and some of the fields from the files I'm using have double quotes in. 
I have this code as you can see I am trying to use the .replace to remove the `"` and replace with `nothing`, this throws an empty char literal error. Is there an easier way of removing all double quotes  `

```
public void Manipulatefile(string csv, string suffix)
    {
        StringBuilder formattedData = new StringBuilder();

        // Read all file lines into a string array.
        string path = @csv;
        string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        foreach (string fileLine in fileLines)
        {

            string[] lineItems = fileLine.Split(new char[1] { ',' });


            string forename = lineItems[0];


            string surname = lineItems[1];


            formattedData.Append(forename);

            // Add the CSV seperator.
            formattedData.Append(",");

            // Append the forename to the current CSV output line.
            formattedData.Append(surname);


            formattedData.Append(",");

            formattedData.Append(forename.Substring(1,1));
            formattedData.Append(surname);
            formattedData.Append(suffix);

            formattedData.Replace('"', '');
            formattedData.AppendLine();

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test\MyFile.csv", formattedData.ToString());
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: change formattedData.Replace('"', ''); to formattedData.Replace("\"", "");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Replace can accept a string, and an empty string is valid, so just escape the double quotes

```
formattedData.Replace("\"", "");
```

It's worth bearing in mind that your line of code that splits by comma

```
string[] lineItems = fileLine.Split(new char[1] { ',' });
```

will have the undesired effect of splitting any string with a comma in it. The whole point of double quotes is to isolate a comma so that column can contain comma. For example

```
name,address,phone
"Joe","22 acacia avenue, mean street, LA","555-1234"
```

Your code will split this line into five values, not three as expected. You should really use a dedicated CSV parser instead.

Comment: Thank you,
The File that it is opening will be from a SIMS report so I know what the input will be.  
It was the formattedData.Append(",");

            formattedData.Append(forename.Substring(1,1));
           
The substring was pulling in a quote from somewhere but if i used just the forename it didnt.

Comment: in that case you should be safe enough using it. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

A character literal needs to be exactly one character.  A `string` is a sequence of zero or more characters.  You want a string that has no characters, since you can't have a character that represents no character.

There is another overload of `Replace` that accepts strings, rather than characters, for its parameters.

On a side note, CSV files can escape quotes inside of the field value with another quote, so if your field value is: `This is my "Value"` you can write it as `This is my ""Value""` and it will be interpreted properly.  If you're fine removing the quotes entirely in your situation that's fine, just know that there is a defined case for how to actually keep the quotes in without violating the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as an empty char. The closest you can get is `'\0'`, the Unicode "null" character. 
But why don't you use a `string`? You need to escape `"` with `\`:

```
formattedData.Replace("\"", "");
```